# Facebook Realtime not notifying post/comments on recently installed applications

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, real-time

I have recently remade the realtime update for my application. It was up and working since a long time, but at those times you did it all in the browser, no I found that I have to register it through my web app.

Well no problem, but I discovered that I'm only getting updates feed on very old pages that I attached a long time ago. Why am I not getting on newer pages, do I need to set a particular permisssion?

I saw something about adding the application as a tab. I have no idea what this means, where my old pages added as tabs? I have used the FB Javascript API to attach pages. If so how can I fix this with my newer pages, there are a lot of them, some 50 clients are attached now from whom I don't get realtime updates.

It is a waste for me and Facebook to do polling on all my pages so I hope to resolve this, any help is really welcome and please let me know if more information is needed.

Greetings, Tim Mickelson

Answer (score 0):

you need to install your app as a tab-app to receive Facebook realtime updates for every page you want!

Here's a code example:

```
 $subscribed = $this->facebook_og->api($pageId . '/tabs', 'POST', array(
   'app_id' => APP_ID,
   'access_token' => $pageToken
 ));
```

Comment: But is this something documented anywhere or have you empirically learned and if so is it always supported? Please if you know where this is documented could you lead me to the documentation?

I have not seen this documented and I don't understand why client pages that installed the application two or three years ago are picked up by the realtime of Facebook.

Thank you for your support.

Comment: there used to be a documentation, but now it's gone. i don't find it anymore in the official docs. but, of course, this code is tested!

Comment: I'm sure the code is tested and works fine, it's just that before taking the decision to rework the process of adding facebook channels to our platform and making a process of fixing all the pages from facebook I would like to see an official document that this is really neccessary and supported. It will have a certain cost and the company is not mine. Do you know whom I could ask to get a more official confermation (and that I could ask to put some documentation it seems absurd that one has to do all this and it is not documented)?

Comment: Well, you can ask to directly change the documentation here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0/page/tabs ("Was this document helpful?") Or, you can join the FB Developers Group on Facebook and ask for help there: https://www.facebook.com/groups/fbdevelopers/

In any case: The mentioned documentation contains a vague message, you're looking for: "Publishing: If the app is not configured as a Page tab app in the App Dashboard it will only be installed for the Page and not added as a tab. This is useful if you are subscribing to real-time updates from the Page."

Comment: I used the page token and added the app as a tab from the Graph Explorer, and as suggested by you it started to work. This is a bit of a pain since I need to do this to all pages, and also implement this on adding new pages. But first I will contact FB to update some documentation because it is really not documented. After adding as a "tab" it is not visible on the page as tab, and I can't list it on the Graph Explorer (as documented) it is in no way visible to me. How can I see that I actually added it as a tab?  If I try to delete the app Facebook gives an error "App is not installed"